# ANTLR not generating ParserBase

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR and was looking into the CPP14 grammar [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cpp). I tried using

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 CPP14Lexer.g4`

`antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 CPP14Parser.g4`

Then use the following driver code:

```
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from CPP14Lexer import CPP14Lexer
from CPP14Parser import CPP14Parser

def main(argv):
    input_stream = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = CPP14Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = CPP14Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.start_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

And, try running it to parse a Hello World code in cpp, but I get the following error:

```
python Driver.py example.cc                                                                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vedantamohapatra/antlr/Driver.py", line 4, in <module>
    from CPP14Parser import CPP14Parser
  File "/Users/vedantamohapatra/antlr/CPP14Parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    from CPP14ParserBase import CPP14ParserBase
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CPP14ParserBase'
```

How should I go about correcting this?

Comment: Many grammars in the grammars-v4 repo contain target-specific code. Target-specific files are place in a directory named after the target, e.g., Python3. You must first copy those files to where the grammar resides. Then, run `python transformGrammar.py` to replace code in the grammar to Python3. Understand that C++ uses a preprocessor. The grammar does not do preprocessor expansion, but simply considers them the same as comments. So, it is possible for input to contain preprocessor directives that may cause the parse to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first [run transformGrammar.py](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/Python3/transformGrammar.py), and then also [CPP14ParserBase.py](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/cpp/Python3/CPP14ParserBase.py) before running your driver file.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't actually see that there was a ParserBase in the repo itself. I thought ANTLR would be generating that for us

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine. Sometimes, the generated parser needs some target specific code, in which case there is a base-lexer and/or -parser in the repo. In this case, somewhere in the grammar there is a method called `IsPureSpecifierAllowed` that checks something. The implementation of this function is target specific, and the implementation defined in the base-parser.